# Inviting the GOD inside human body

Tags: belief, gods

In Temples at some places there are saints or Sadhus or Babas who say they have seen GOD, there are some people who say  that GOD has entered their body.

- I have seen one incident myself : when the Baba say that GOD has
  entered their  body, they (Babas) wobble their body and head. Some say that Goddess has arrived and She is performing these acts (*Mata ayi hai*). Is this possible that some GOD can enter in human body
  and annotate messages OR is this just a fake? Because this is happening
  from long time in Hinduism and can be seen even today in
  villages. What is truth here?
- The disease of **Chechak** (**Small pox** I guess) is also said to be related to **Devi Mata**. Is their any story or incident regarding it?

Comment: 30% are lunatics. 50% are charlatans. 20% are being taken over by ghosts that say they are gods.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda woo woo woo, **Ghosts**???

Comment: Yes, mischievous ghosts can take over weak minds. They should be avoided at all costs. I have been blessed in my lifetime with having met several true sadhaks. There is no movement of the body as you describe. If asked bluntly, they give an evasive answer. They do not bring any publicity onto themselves. There are no annotated 'messages' especially in a public forum. Communion with God is a private experience.

Comment: I agree with @SwamiVishwananda's mention on ghosts

Comment: These fake acts are done mostly in Villages of Grama devatas.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, it happens because I am also one of them. Goddess Bajra Yodini enters in my body too. When she enters I can see the past, present and the future of a person. I can even say about unknown persons too at first sight.

Comment: What? Seriously ? Please give some examples or true facts, I am looking forward for your response.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda How to we create strong minds in the sense you said?

Answer (score 5):

Let's first talk about religion view:

Yes, it is possible that GOD(but in most cases there will be goddess) can come inside of person's(Again in most cases person will be 'she') body. But this happen at **specific time**(like sandhya means evening time) and with **specific environment**(where doop, nagara, tons of agarbatti's smoke like typical devi-mandir but all are too much!). This will be the normal scenario when you find goddess come inside of human body.

Now, let's talk about scientific view(Bases on what I search):

1. When you agree for some god, and you pray for long time, you get some of god's characteristics in side of you.
2. Now, when you get environment which i just describe above, it will make vibration inside of your body and active one of seven chakra.
3. But your body is not capable of taking power of this active chakra, so that your body started to vibrate and all this *head moves in circle* things happen.
4. And seems your chakra is active(for that short time only), you get power of say, to able to view of some future events. (and telling about future answer is what we call goddess's speak)

   But here, I want to mention that, not every one can active chakra even for specific time, in most cases people are doing for money.

One fun thing: There was lady who did these type of things and identifies herself as 'MATAJI', but we know that she was totally faking. So, one day what my friend did, when she is doing this(as *mataji come inside here*) my friend made fake call on his cell phone and spoke loudly as 'what dipak is in hospital?', now dipak is her son, and she suddenly stop and take cellphone.

After this we never go at her home(because if we go we will she and her family definitely hit us), so did other people(because they knew that she is lying).

Comment: @nobalG Their residual bad karma will make the chakra to deactivate. If more the bad karma,less the time it takes to deactivate . That's reason why highly noble saints won't wobble their body and can make chakra stable in activated mode

Answer (score 3):

Human is in itself Divine.

> || Tat Tvam Asi ||

A body is like some field, that is *"Kshetra"*. And one who resides in the body is *"Kshetragya"*. And that Himself, i.e *"JeevaAtma"* which is God.

**Space and Time** are illusions around us. Another great illusion is the **Free Will.**

Like in M-theory that sees the worlds as a 3-D "membrane" moving in higher dimensional cosmos. There could be many coexisting membrane, may be just side by side, but one totally unaware of the other.

Similarly, there are *"Lokas"* all around us, which we can not see or perceive. When a *"Jeevatma"* leaves a body, and its attachments, it moves through parallel universes. A spacial dimensional unimaginable, but in few fractions of a second.

What we call a 'Ghost' could be "anybody" from a different dimensions, or a soul in *"PretYoni"*, because of its *Karma* or left attachments. So that the soul is unable to move on to other dimension and still dwelling in subtle form on earth.

So God never has to enter a human body because He's already there. People do say *"Devi"* entering into a body in exaggeration or superstition. A female Goddess is considered a consort of God. So if **God is the Universal Consciousnes**s, his **Consort is the all pervading Energy** OF the material world.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to comment on fake people who do these for money or fame or for livelihood.

With my understanding I can say.. Based on one's  previous birth samskara (derived good characters from previous birth) one may attain a state with minimal effort compared to others. People cant stay in that state for much time, their karma brings them down to their actual stage. This is the stage where more people makes a false step and this is when a Sadguru is required to guide them and help them reach higher stages. In this journey one may be blessed with asthasiddis and nava nidhis, one should not fall as a prey but treat them as a milestone or a checkpoint and has to proceed further for their spiritual enlightenment.

The only strong note I say is a true sadhak/devotee won't reveal his state because the state itself comes with abundant energy, peace and happiness, it requires no second person intervention. These stages cannot be explained but can only be experienced. Sadhak should not reveal his state because it may bring pride & ego factors. If its revealed to others, people may come to him to get blessed with worldly pleasures which again will throw sadhak to life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think people who are thinking that god enter into a human body are wrong. I'm saying it because I have learnt many thing about this. This is totally a drama, because how can god enter into a body?

I have seen this drama in my own home, then I searched about it. When they started the drama, the body started moving, it's also part of an acting.

It's physiological disease. That time, you put your hand on the head and easily thinking positively that they are related to god. One more thing, of course god is in earth, as a positive thinking. God is in you, in me, in other, so use him in your work. They help you too much.

Answer (score 0):

I have also noticed this if God has entered somebody's body. How come they predict and talk only about their family and not about others.

Here I have seen we have to ask them a question then only they will answer... We all have been knowing this fact that God is "Antaryami" means he knows everything and can read our mind then why doesn't that happen when God enters somebody's body.

Nothing magical happens when God enters.