# Do the Scriptures say anything about Spiritual Possession?

Tags: belief

Do the Scriptures mention anything about Spiritual Possession of other beings or objects? If so, then how to exorcise?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3314/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan how is that even close to a possible duplicate?

Comment: Because that's a question about people's bodies being possessed by gods.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan where does the question say gods? All kinds of beings, spirit, demonic, or gods. Also asking about objects...

Answer (score 2):

**Do the Scriptures mention anything about Spiritual Possession of other beings or objects?**

Yes, the Scriptures mention about Spiritual Possession of other beings. For an instance, as per **Mahabharata: Anusasana Parva: [Section XL](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b005.htm) - [Section XLI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b006.htm)**,

There was a blessed rishi Devasarman. He has a wife named Ruchi who was very beautiful. The rishi also had a disciple Vipula (of Bhrigu's race).

Once Devasarman called his disciple Vipula and said

> 'I shall leave home (for a while) in order to perform a sacrifice. The chief of the celestials always covets this Ruchi of mine. Do thou, during my absence, protect her, putting forth all thy might! Thou shalt pass thy time heedfully in view of Purandara. O foremost one of Bhrigu's race, that Indra assumes various disguises.'

Vipula promised his guru to protect Ruchi from Indra and Devasarman, intend upon performing a sacrifice, set out from his abode.

Vipula began to think how he can protect his guru's wife from Indra and finally reached to this conclusion:

> Indra cannot be kept out by enclosing this retreat of ours or fencing this yard, since he is capable of assuming innumerable forms. Assuming the form of the wind, the chief of the celestials may assault the spouse of my preceptor. The best course, therefore, for me, would be **to enter (by Yoga-power) the body of this lady** and remain there.

And

> Directing his eyes then to hers and uniting the rays of light that emanated from her organs of vision with those that issued from his, Vipula (in his subtile form) entered the lady's body even as the element of wind enters that of ether of space. Penetrating her eyes with his eyes and her face with his face, Vipula stayed, without moving, within her invisibly, like her shadow. Restraining every part of the lady's body, Vipula continued to dwell within her, intent on protecting her from Indra. The lady herself knew nothing of this.

One day Indra assuming a form of celestial beauty entered the ascetic's abode. Seeing Indra come in that guise, her (Ruchi's) wonder having been excited at the unrivalled beauty of form which the person (disguised Indra) possessed, she very much wished to ask him as to who he was.

> Although, however, she wished to rise up and offer him a welcome, yet her limbs having been restrained by Vipula who was dwelling within her, she failed, O king, to do what she wished. In fact, she was unable to move from the place where she sat.

Later Indra addressed the lady in many way then, the lady endeavoured to answer him.

> Vipula, however restrained the words that she intended to utter. The words, therefore, that actually escaped her lips (under the influence of Vipula) were. 'What is the reason of thy coming hither?'

Then, observing that awkward result, Indra saw every thing with his spiritual eye. He then beheld the ascetic staying within the body of the lady.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Yogis are able to perform this function of able to control thoughts of other beings.  Sri Paramahansa Yogananda in his first public speech, felt little 
nervous, then suddenly his body was taken by his Guru to deliver a soul stirring
speech, which Sri Paramahansa Yoganda discreetly asked others to get to know what
transpired during the event
Similary, the mother (Yogini Mira Alfasa) disciple of Sri Aurobindo Ghosh states in her sayings "manifestations"
Similarly, it happened with Sri Swami Vivekananda   & Sri Adi Shankaracharya when he entered in to the dead body of local king, to know about palace life.

Such things can only be by advanced spiritual masters who got siddhis, through yogic or spiritual practice.

Comment: How does one prevent possession?