# Can a God or Goddess possess a human's body? In Hindi, the term is called "Mata Ana" / "Mata khelna" / "Mata ka Darbar"

Tags: gods, goddess

I've come across such instances, after which the person possessed by the God/Goddess goes into a trance like state and answers questions/grants boons, which sometimes come true.

This occurrence is common and I have seen videos of people and also know people who are regularly possessed by a God / Goddess. There are many videos on YouTube too. Can this happen? If yes, how does it work?

This sometimes happens during Navratri. In Marathi, it's called "Angat Devi" (Goddess in body). In some cases, the person is able to call the God / Goddess at will (several times a week).

This is a serious question, I really need to know. I can share videos on YouTube if needed.

I read the other related question on this topic and my query was not fully satisfied, so I request you to please keep my question open.

How are the boons coming true? How are they able to tell about past events accurately?

Comment: I think it is fake. I haven't come across any scriptures which mention this type of practise. Moreover, it is strange why would the deva/devi not come in another material body?

Comment: Nice Q. More than goddess herself, it could be one of the dakini or yogini or something. If it’s mata (goddess) then it’s fake.

Comment: Ya seen it personally, no idea if some scripture describes it or not. To describe it: they loose their control over body, dance. Especially if the hairs are tied they will untie them. One specific instance I saw her to take camphor on fire and put it in mouth.

Comment: I dont know about will power, but this gets intiated by listing to puja, stotra and other chantings. And they really aren't in the state of giving boon and talking. It's like total loss of control. This is common in Certain proograms or rituals like jagran and gondhal which happen in Maharashtra which are conducted after marriage or something else.

Comment: @Archit- No idea who dakini and yogini is, but I have encountered such happenings and the person possessed introduces themselves as Goddess (usually some form of Adi Shakti). Could you please give more insight?

Comment: @Proxy- I have encountered such happenings where the possessed person suddenly claims to be a Goddess and speaks to the people gathered as a Goddess, and then she grants boons, solves problems etc.

Comment: @Wikash_- Oh okay. I have no idea, that's why I'm trying to get the opinion and insight of others.

Comment: @Archit- Just read about Dakinis and Yoginis. Dakinis appear to be good, and Yoginis are created by one of the Matrikas? So both are good / positive entities, correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inviting the GOD inside human body](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/inviting-the-god-inside-human-body) and [Do the Scriptures say anything about Spiritual Possession?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7988/do-the-scriptures-say-anything-about-spiritual-possession/29117#29117)

Comment: @YDS- Thanks for sharing. I read through it, but the opinion is divided, and I want more details. How are the predictions / boons coming true if it is not Goddess? How are they able to predict the future? How does this mechanism work?

Comment: and how would an ordinary person tell the difference between a possession of a person by a 'divine personage' and a mischievous ghost or just a fake?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda- Not sure i understand your comment. Please explain. If it is a gost, how are some past and future events being told correctly, and boons being granted?

Comment: @sv.- No, it does not. But thanks for sharing.